# Send only date and not time to date field in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm trying to update a `DATE` (not `DATETIME`) column in SQL Server, but when I execute the SQL command, it is posted with time format also.

```
string datetosql = "10.4.2015";

            string sqlQuery = "UPDATE tbl_tasks " +
                                "SET description = '" + tbTaskDescription.Text + "', " +
                                "deadline = '" + datetosql + "' , " +
                                "status = '" + statusIndex.ToString() + "' " +
                                "WHERE tid = " + _TaskID;
```

When I later collect the date using `SqlDataReader`, it is posted with time format: `04.10.2015 00:00:00`. Why is this happening?

Comment: What data type is the column `deadline` in the table `tbl_tasks` ?

Comment: If the Sql datatype is `DATE`, then it will not store a time part at all. The time part is probably presented because you are reading the DATE back into a .Net DateTime before presenting it.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET doesn't have a date only data type.

If you ask to return a SQL Server `date`, or a `time`, it always returns a `DateTime` struct instance in .NET. For a `date`, the time properties (hours, minutes, etc.) will be `0`.

Note that using queries that aren't parameterized is considered bad! You are open for SQL injection, and you make your life harder since you need to escape quotes, etc.

Comment: `System.DateTime.Date` - even though it's a `DateTime`, but the time-properties are eliminated :)

Comment: So it still returns `0` for hours, minutes, seconds. Doesn't help OP. (it is about the returning data, which you can't influence directly)

Comment: Thank you. And I know about sql injections, just tried to make it as simple as possible at the moment.

Comment: @Skram: No problem. Just to give you the heads up.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: On my mind too, but I didn't want to confuse OP. Thanks for the addition.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `cast` to `datetosql`, ex:

```
Cast(datetosql as Date)
```